# How can I change the text and icon colors for tabBarItems in iOS 7?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar, uitabbaritem, ios7

How can I change the text and icon colors for UITabBar and UITabBarItems in iOS 7? The default gray text seems dim and hard to read for unselected tabbar items.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two things you need to do for this:

1) If you want to customize the TabBar itself, you need to set the barTintColor for the tabBarController:

```objc
    // this will generate a black tab bar
    tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // this will give selected icons and text your apps tint color
    tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = appTintColor;  // appTintColor is a UIColor *
```

2) Set the tabBarItem text appearance for each state that you want to override:

```objc
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : appTintColor
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateSelected];


// doing this results in an easier to read unselected state then the default iOS 7 one
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Ed covers just about everything you need here, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to adjust the other tabs colors. So far the only option is using images.

Comment: How do you set the unselected icon color?

Comment: This doesn't change the color of the unselected items. Only way seems to be to use images as below.

Comment: size 10 font? A little small?

Comment: @Pwner I also want to unselected icon color, I found that using the correct image, and rendering it as an original mode is one way. Please tell me if you found any other way.

Answer (score 44):

This worked for me, to tint not active items in the tabbar

```
UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
```

// here you need to use the icon with the color you want, as it will be rendered as it is

```
item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

// this icon is used for selected tab and it will get tinted as defined in

```
self.tabBar.tintColor
item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to change the color of the unselected tabs.

Comment: Using `imageWithRenderingMode` is the key to change tab image colors

Comment: awesome solution and the only solution that worked... btw any ways to change the tab item's title color as well ?

Answer (score 12):

Ed's answer is perfect, but let me add one thing.
TabBar is in default translucent thus affected by the color of view under the TabBar (i.e. each member viewController's view's color affects TabBar appearance.).

So I set below code not to be affected.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false;
```

Together with Ed's answer here is a complete code I use now.

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 8):

Code free way to change text color in tab bar:

If you are just using iOS 10 then you may change the Image Tint in your Tab Bar

[image]

If you are also supporting iOS 9 and lower, then you must also add tintColor to your user definer runtime attributes in each tab bar item

[image]

if you also wish to change your icon color make sure the correct color image is in your assest folder and change Render as to Original Image

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Tested in iOS 8 for permanent text color (selected/unselected) and image colors (selected/unselected) **without** create two images with different colors foreach tab:

**Text color:**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor: selectedTabColor ];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       **yourFont**, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                       ** selectedTabColor**, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       **yourFont**, NSFontAttributeName,
                                                       **selectedTabColor**, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**Images color:** (assuming that the original images have the color you want display as unselected)

In a **UITabBarController** subclass -awakeFromNib :

```
    for (int i =0; i<self.viewControllers.count; i++)
    {
        UITabBarItem *tab = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i];
        tab.image = [tab.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    }
```

*Credits: the whole internet and stack overflow XD*

Comment: Thank you! Do you maybe know how to add separators like on this image?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u6jk2yv4kugfpg/Screenshot%202015-10-11%2014.26.42.png?dl=0

Comment: for that one probably you need to subclass the tab bar or the tab bar item

Answer (score 3):

This Should Work Perfectly for iOS 8 also

For unselected tabbar item:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
```

For selected tabbar item:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

Comment: color gets changed on tab switching

Comment: Then Don't use [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

Comment: [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mytrip_tab_selected"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mytrip_tab"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

Comment: The above comment will work when having two same images with different colors.we can present by selecting and un-selecting  the UITabbar Items.

Comment: @Usharao nice code for unselected icons, but I have a specific requirement, that only one tab item should have different color.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `self.tabBarController.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;` to make the tab bar black

Answer (score 0):

You try it

```
for (UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBarController.tabBar.items) {
        item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"youimage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                           nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youimage.png"];
    }
```

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor is deprecated in iOS7

Answer (score 0):

@Usharao answer above worked for me;

My problem was on startup all my TabBarItems
seemed to be in a selected state, all having the same "Blue" tinted colour.
By selecting all the tabs one by one the coloured state would become corrected.

I used this code below in my AppDelegate class: (compatible for >= IOS9)

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UITabBar class]]] 
                                        setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now from `iOS10` one can use

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy, nullable) UIColor *unselectedItemTintColor
```

to change default color for `TabBarItem` image and text at unselected state.

Thus, the pair of properties `tintColor` and `unselectedItemTintColor` gives us full control on items colors.