# Tab bar item tint color

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

In iOS 7, I been developing an app that uses the UITabBarController and I noticed that the tab bar items stay gray even tho I change the tint color of the tab bar. Is there any way to change the color of non-selected tab bar items?

Comment: This tutorial can be useful for you: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming

Comment: Above link does not work. @roher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this:: follow a simple approach..

1. Change tintColor as you want
2. Add a new set of images for unselected items and render them in original mode.

For more info, read through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665559/1307844)

Comment: Put a correct coloured image is solution, and renderMode should be original is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

To sets the tint color globally for the app, you need to add below code In app `delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method`:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:13.0/255.0 green:116.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `tabBar.tintColor` property is the right way to do it, however to make it work we need to tell iOS to ignore color properties of the `UIImage` in `TabBarItem`.
Hence write this code in your custom `TabBarViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()`

```
for item in self.tabBar.items ?? [] {
    item.selectedImage = item.selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    item.image = item.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
}
```