# Change tab bar item selected color in a storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to change my tab bar items to be pink when selected instead of the default blue.

How can i accomplish this using the storyboard editor in Xcode 6?

Here are my current setting which are not working, the blue background works but the pink doesnt work:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tab-bar-item-tint-color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361101/tab-bar-item-tint-color)!

Comment: Check this answer it will help you for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727092/7804300

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Add Runtime Color attribute named "tintColor" from StoryBoard. This is working(**for Xcode 8 and above**).

if you want unselected color.. you can add `unselectedItemTintColor` too.

[image: setting tintColor as Runtime Attribute]

Comment: it worked for me when I added this property to UITabBarItem and not UITabBar.

Comment: Any reason why it doesn't work with the option attribute ?

Comment: Xcode bug, nothing else. I have also found too many bugs of using UITextView inside UITableViewCell using from storyboard in Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Actually, value of any property can be set from User Defined Attributes, so, instead of programmatically setting tintColor property, i used to set directly from xib

Comment: @MehulThakkar how can I do this with the font size of Title of the item ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli: Not getting, what you are asking for

Comment: I want to change the font size of the Title of TabBarItem. Can I do it from storyboard they way you changed the TintColor.

Comment: No, you cant, you can only set properties of given UI-Object, now, UITabbarItem doesn't have any property for font size

Comment: you can change font size by programmatically writing following code `[tab.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
  forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: But how do you set the tab bar item UNselected color in storyboard?

Comment: Works perfect for my case - I need my five tabBar items to be unique colours when selected. I was able to set this Runtime Attribute on the `UITabBarItem`, on the `UINavigationController` connected to my tabBar and it works flawlessly. All without writing any code too which is great, as I am reusing a VC class three times. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem in xcode 7.3.1 so if its a bug its still unresolved...

Comment: conversely - this is the only approach that works on iOS 10 (tint from attributes panel seems to not work, and runtime attribute "tintColor" of uitabbaritem doesn't work too.

Comment: Worked well on iOS 10.

Comment: `UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.3647058824, blue: 0.1450980392, alpha: 1)` work for me ...

Answer (score 201):

This elegant solution works great on **SWIFT 3.0**, **SWIFT 4.2** and **SWIFT 5.1**:

On the Storyboard:

1. Select your **Tab Bar**
2. Set a *Runtime Attibute* called **tintColor** for the desired color of the **Selected Icon** on the tab bar
3. Set a *Runtime Attibute* called **unselectedItemTintColor** for the desired color of the **Unselected Icon** on the tab bar

[image]

Edit: Working **with Xcode 8/10, for iOS 10/12 and above**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. unselectedItemTintColor finds very rare

Comment: 'unselectedItemTintColor' perfect solution for me thanks.

Comment: Will this work if deployment target is 8.0 or 9.0? I have used swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0 for development

Comment: Important to select the Tab bar, indeed worked in Swift 4 for me.

Comment: Excellent! Still working on xCode 10 :) does not refresh the visual editor but works once compiled :)

Comment: worked on Xcode 10, iOS 12. Does the name must be ```tintColor``` and ```unselectedItemTintColor ``` then Xcode could use it?

Comment: Yes @ChuckZHB.
Names must be tintColor and unselectedItemTintColor.

Answer (score 71):

In Swift, using xcode 7 (and later), you can add the following to your AppDelegate.swift file:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

This is the what the complete method looks like:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // I added this line
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return true
}
```

In the example above my item will be white. The "/255.0" is needed because it expects a value from 0 to 1. For white, I could have just used 1. But for other color you'll probably be using RGB values.

Comment: It seems none of the other method works (any more.) This works!

Comment: @Jarrod I was fooling around with this for almost 1 hr, this answer should have more votes. Thanks!

Answer (score 56):

On `Xcode8` I have changed the `ImageTint` from the storyboard and it works well.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: When using custom images THIS IS the one that worked for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It doesn't require a runtime attribute which means this works in Launch screens!

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 3 | Xcode 10**

*If you want to **make all tab bar items the same color** (selected & unselected)...*

---

**Step 1**

Make sure your image assets are setup to *Render As = Template Image*. This allows them to inherit color.

[image: Xcode Assets]

---

**Step 2**

Use the storyboard editor to change your tab bar settings as follows:

- Set *Tab Bar: Image Tint* to the color you want the selected icon to inherit.
- Set *Tab Bar: Bar Tint* to the color you want the tab bar to be.
- Set *View: Tint* to the color you want to see in the storyboard editor, this doesn't affect the icon color when your app is run.

[image: Xcode Storyboard Editor]

---

**Step 3**

Steps 1 & 2 will change the color for the selected icon. If you still want to change the color of the unselected items, you need to do it in code. I haven't found a way to do it via the storyboard editor.

Create a custom tab bar controller class...

```
//  TabBarController.swift

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make unselected icons white
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

... and assign the custom class to your tab bar scene controller.

[image: Xcode Storyboard Editor]

---

If you figure out how to change the unselected icon color via the storyboard editor please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white`
`self.tabBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2, green: 0.7333333333, blue: 0.3450980392, alpha: 1)` 
Work for me

Answer (score 14):

This best way is to change `Image Tint` in storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 10):

put this code in the viewDidLoad of the view controller that you want to change the color of

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Is there no way to change for all of the tabs?

Comment: Just put the code with the same color in the view did load of all of your tabs

Comment: you can use this code right after you make your UITabController , it will set the colour you mentioned for all tab items on selection.

Comment: There's no such method setSelectedImageTintColor

Answer (score 8):

You can also set selected image bar tint color by key path:

[image]

Hope this will help you!! Thanks

Comment: in iOS 9 it doesn't change the unselected color

Comment: How would that help in changing color of UITabBar icon ?

Answer (score 7):

XCode 8.2, iOS 10, Swift 3: now there's an `unselectedItemTintColor` attribute for `tabBar`:

```
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 200/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change colors UITabBarItem by storyboard but if you want to change colors by code it's very easy:

// Use this for change color of selected bar

```
   [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

// This for change unselected bar (iOS 10)

```
   [[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

// And this line for change color of all tabbar

```
   [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: setUnselectedItemTintColor  is for only iOS 10

Answer (score 5):

Somehow we are not able to change the Tab Bar selected item Tint color using storyboard alone, hence I added below code in my ViewDidLoad, hope this helps.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution in Swift 3 that works in iOS 10:

Firstly, you create your own tab bar controller subclass and add it to your tab controller in your storyboard. In the `viewDidLoad()` method you can then customize the tab bar. It should be stated here that the `tintColor` attribute of the `tabBar` represents the color of the selected item not the color of the unselected ones! In order to change the color of the unselected items, I recommend looping through each item and use the original colors of your images, so they are not rendered as grey automatically.

```
class CustomTabBarVC: UITabBarController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.tintColor = AppColor.normalRed
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
        self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true

        if let items = self.tabBar.items
        {
            for item in items
            {
                if let image = item.image
                {
                    item.image = image.withRenderingMode( .alwaysOriginal )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only downside with this approach is that your item images must already have the desired color you aim for.

Comment: Complicated. Jarrod's answer works well with all icons.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code in your app delegate -did_finish_launching_with_options function

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(255/255.0), green: CGFloat(99/255.0), blue: CGFloat(95/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )
```

put the RGB of the required color

Answer (score 5):

Image Tint from storyboard worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass the `UITabBarController`, and replace the one with it in the storyboard.
In your `viewDidLoad` implementation of subclass call this:

```
[self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: getting: `'UITabBar' does not have a member named 'setSelectedImageTintColor'`

Comment: Also i am using swift so I put: `self.tabBar.setSelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.greenColor` not sure if that is correct or not

Comment: @Deekor it's `tintColor` not `selectedImageTintColor`, btw `selectedImageTintColor` is deprecated in iOS 8.