# iOS8 Swift TabBarController Change Icon Color

Tags: swift, colors, ios8, icons, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to change the color of the icons in my TabBarController.
I've successfully changed the textcolor (just below the icons), but cant figure out how I change the icon color.

I've changed the icon-text-color like this:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()], forState:.Selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Normal)
```

I've put this into my AppDelegate.swift (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions).
Now the selected item-text is orange, and the unselected are white.
The icons however are still in blue / dark gray. How do I change these?

Unselected:

[image: Unselected]

Selected:

[image: Selected]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tab bar item selected color in a storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `tintColor` property by UIAppearance.

Comment: Thank you, I was now able to change the color of the selected item.
But how do I change the color of the unselected items-icons?

Comment: I think you need to use `init(title:image:selectedImage:)` to create UITabBarItem instances, and the images should be configured as `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`. Check the UITabBarItem reference.

Answer (score 2):

being tBVC my tabBarViewController, I just do:

```
tBVC.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "k-lenda(Hi)")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
tBVC.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "k-lenda(Lo)")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

And in the attributes inspector I have the "Hi" image for the Bar Item.

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.