# Changing UITabBarItem image's color

Tags: icons, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, selected, swift2

I'm having an hard time trying to change the color of my `UITabBarItem`'s icon. I used the code below to initialize all the parameters:

```
// Settings Tab
    tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = false
    tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = dark_color

    let titoli:[String] = ["Feed","Categorie","Info"]
    for (var i:Int=0; i<titoli.count; i++){
        let tab:UITabBarItem? = tabBarController?.tabBar.items![i] as UITabBarItem?
        tab?.image = UIImage(named: titoli[i])
        tab?.title = titoli[i]
        tab?.setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(object: UIColor.whiteColor(), forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName) as? [String:AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        tab?.setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(object: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6), forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName) as? [String:AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

Am I missing something here?
FYI: just playing with **XCode Beta** and **Swift 2.0**

Comment: What happens? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard/29673404#29673404) but in short, click on the tab bar item you wish to change and you can add a new runtime attribute in the Storyboard which will change the entire item (image & text) when selected.