# Change the color of selected tab bar icon in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I found out how to change the color of the text of the tab bar item when it is selected, but I am wondering how to do the same for the icon. I can't seem to find the solution on SO for swift, and that works. My icon has uploaded correctly, and when deselected is gray, but when it is selected, it goes to the default blue color. I would like to change this to a certain red. Where do I do this, and how do I do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673404/3403364) but in short, click on the tab bar item you wish to change and you can add a new runtime attribute in the Storyboard which will change the entire item (image & text) when selected.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that post, I had done the same thing, but when you write in tintColor, for me it had been deleting that word and going back to keyPath. Once I saved it, i re-edited it and it worked. Thanks!