# How do I change the color of unselected tabs, preferably in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, tintcolor

Here is an answer on how to change the color of the selected tab:

[Change tab bar item selected color in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard)

How do I change the color of the unselected tabs? Short of adding custom images for selected/unselected, which seems like too much hassle for this simple task.

Comment: Too much hassle? Really? It's quite easy. Create the images in another app like Sketch or create them in code. It's only a few lines of code. What are your problems with this approach?

Comment: Perhaps none. Just thought there had to be a 1-liner programmatic solution. Is it impossible to change the color programmatically?

Comment: Sure. But you need to use an image with a the color.

Comment: So no programmatic logic to change the color of an inactive tab? Only of an active one?

Comment: You can change the color of the tabBar in total.

Comment: In storyboard? How? Will that change the foreground, not the background color? (My unselected images are gray on white, and I need to make them a lighter gray)