# how to add colored icon in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, icons, uitabbaritem

I am trying to add an icon which is multicolored and when I added the icon as per in the tab bar, it is showing a single color blue, the actual colors of the icon are not visible?

how should I add the colored icon in the tab bar?

Comment: Change ImageTint : You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard/29673404#29673404)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change tab bar item selected color in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard)

Comment: @Arman_Gorjipoor how can we place the original image which has multi color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In assets folder in x-code select your image and in attribute inspector change value of **Render As** to **"Original Image"** instead of **"Default"**.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in a tab bar all images are displayed with rendering mode set to `template`, you can override this behavior forcing rendering mode when loading the image:

```swift
let yourImage = UIImage(named: "your_image")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

and then use your image as a tab bar icon.

Answer (score 0):

It is better do this in code like this:

```
var aViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
```

// This statement is what you need

```
var myTabBarItem: UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"))
aViewController.tabBarItem = myTabBarItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in the storyboard. Try this:

```
extension UITabBarItem {

    convenience init(title: String, unselected: String, selected: String) {

        let selectedImage = UIImage(named: selected)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let unselectedImage = UIImage(named: unselected)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        self.init(title: title, image: unselectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
    }
}
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` in your view controller...

```
tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "My title",
                          unselected: "unselectedIconName",
                          selected: "selectedIconName")
```