# How can I set the tabBarItems to different colours?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I've got a tabBar setup with 5 tabBarItems all going to different view controllers. 
I've set the project up so that when a tabBarItems is not selected, it is a grey tint color on both the text and image (I'm using system default images). What I am looking for is how to set each of the selected tabBarItems to different colors. EG, "Home" would have a red tint to both the text and image; "Social" would have a blue tint to both the text and image; "About" would have a green tint to both the text and image; etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Already answered ([Change tab bar item selected color in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard/29673404#29673404)) but in short, click on the tab bar item you wish to change and you can add a new runtime attribute in the Storyboard which will change the entire item (image & text) when selected.May Be its Helpful For you.

Comment: Hi, i've tried following this, have added a tintColor to each of the tabBarItems but they all still have the same single color (which I can change, just not indiviudally)

Answer (score 0):

**If you define bar items**, you can do it like this:

> let array = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.green]

implement UITabBarDelegate

```
@IBOutlet weak var tab3: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var tab2: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var tab1: UITabBarItem!

func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item == tab1 {
        tabBar.tintColor = array[0]
    }else if item == tab2 {
        tabBar.tintColor = array[1]
    }else {
        tabBar.tintColor = array[2]
    }
}
```

If **you use TabBarController** add this code to each viewControllers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .green // change the color for each viewControllers
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, i'm new to swift - where would I add this code? To every one of the ViewControllers?

Comment: Hi, I think you are using tabBarController so I edited my answer.

Comment: Thats amazing!! Thank you :)