# iOS 7/8 how to set tab bar text color

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I have set color for tab bar in app delegate:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

It works perfect, but I also need to set text color separately. I want my image to be tint with red color, but the text has to be white color.

Is this possible to make?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412010/how-to-change-the-color-of-text-in-uitabbaritem-in-ios-5

Answer (score 5):

to change the color of `uitabbaritem` used `setTitleTextAttributes` I hope this code help you :

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [[uicolor whitecolor] }
       forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

to change the image tintcolor :

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redcolor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734795/860343 covers most of the edits you may need to do for the tab bar items.

In short here is the code:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0f],
                                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName : appTintColor
                                                } forState:UIControlStateSelected];


// doing this results in an easier to read unselected state then the default iOS 7 one

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:1]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```