# Can I change the text and icon colors for every UITabBarItem in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

[image]

I checked this question, [How can I change the text and icon colors for tabBarItems in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734794/how-can-i-change-the-text-and-icon-colors-for-tabbaritems-in-ios-7) but it doesn't give me a solution for iOS 6 nor does it give me a solution so that each `UITabBarItem` will have a different background color and change color upon tapping.

Comment: Why are you trying to support iOS 6? iOS 9 will be in beta next month.

Comment: @rmaddy some clients wants it backward compatible... i dont know why..