# How to change color of TabBarItem when its set enabled False

Tags: ios

I disabled tabBar item then bar button became grey .

I want to change its color but could not do.its by default grey.

When I setEnabled true then its showing original color white.

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:FALSE];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the text and icon colors for tabBarItems in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734794/how-can-i-change-the-text-and-icon-colors-for-tabbaritems-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in `appDelegate` it works fine for me.

```
 [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

 [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

but when i set enable False in `viewController` class then it will become grey.

Comment: still i have not any solution for that dimmed button of tab Bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // this will generate a red tab bar
    tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // this will give selected icons and text your apps tint color
    tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**Update :**

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = false;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: but when i use 
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
it look grey after setEnabled False TabBarItem .

Comment: I would like to disable the currently selected TabBarItem to prevent the user from taping on the same item again .

To do that, I disable the currently selected TabBar Item.
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:currentIndex]setEnabled:FALSE];
My problem is that when I disable the item. It becomes partially dimmed. So the Item is selected and its enabled property is set to FALSE.
Under these conditions, the dimmers (due to the setEnable:FALSE) "wins" and the TabBarItem image dimmed down instead of highlighted.s there a way to prevent the dimmed effect ?

Comment: omg u don;t need to disable it , all what u need is when user hit the button again check if user already load this view or set flag userhitMidTap= yes and don;t run your code if yes

Comment: i could not set tag and call delegates, because there are two screens will be open conditionally so i have to disable first tab bar item